# Issue with setting up app to virtual device on Android

Tags: android, appium, adb

When trying to run the code on IntelliJ to start session through Appium and Android Studio for Virtual device, getting an error code

Encountered internal error running command: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/avetikbabayan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm install /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/8157f64ab162d91e2759d6a47a257a4b7e88edef.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: ''; Code: '1'
[W3C] Error: Command '/Users/avetikbabayan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm install /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/8157f64ab162d91e2759d6a47a257a4b7e88edef.apk' exited with code 1

Android Studio v. 3.6.1
Appium v 1.13.0
OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

it was running previously, just added a new parameter at desired capabilities for add timeout, then removed it. Started not to work properly. 
Tried to re-install android studio and Appium. Didn't helped.
removed all properties on Mac after previous installation, still the same issue
would appreciate a help with this

Comment: Would you please add your code snippet of starting the session here? (setup block)

Comment: [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/avetikbabayan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm install /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/8157f64ab162d91e2759d6a47a257a4b7e88edef.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: ''; Code: '1'
[W3C] Error: Command '/Users/avetikbabayan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm install /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/8157f64ab162d91e2759d6a47a257a4b7e88edef.apk' exited with code 1

Comment: This was the only error containing part.
I can't attach raw log files from Appium
The initial (setup) part is as below

Comment: alling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/avetikbabayan/Desktop/Android_Latest_Tests/android-e2e/app-base-debug.apk","newCommandTimeout":600,"appWaitActivity":"com.***.android.aware.ui.splash.SplashScreenActivity","appWaitPackage":"com.***.android.aware.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"Android Emulator"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"/Users/avetikbabayan/Desktop/Android_Latest_Tests/android-e2e/app-base-debug.apk"

Comment: appium:appWaitActivity":"com.***.android.aware.ui.splash.SplashScreenActivity","appium:appWaitPackage":"com.***.android.aware.debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Android Emulator","appium:newCommandTimeout":600,"platformName":"android","appium:udid":"emulator-5554"}]}]

Comment: I mean your code, not appium log. (The setup block is enough)

Comment: Which part of code, exactly? Setup area - like basic capabilities info or something else?

Comment: Setup area which starts the appium. including capabilities and drivers initialization

Comment: File app = new File("app-base-debug.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 600);
    remoteUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
Appium logs:
[W3C] Calling

Comment: AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/*****.apk","newCommandTimeout":600,"appWaitActivity":"*****.ui.splash.SplashScreenActivity","appWaitPackage":"****.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"Android Emulator"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"/*****.apk","appium:appWaitActivity":"*****.ui.splash.SplashScreenActivity","appium:appWaitPackage":"*****debug","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Android Emulator","appium:newCommandTimeout":600,"platformName":"android","appium:udid":"emulator-5554"}]}]

Comment: I've created a doc, with the all Appium logs on it
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13L6qC2NOuGH1XmiDWi7tVmWL_KvNrXlLmbm4BrPOIsk/edit

Comment: we have no access to this doc